# What is the simplest library for reading email messages in Java without dealing directly with JavaMail API?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm looking for a simple java library that would let me read the content of email messages for testing purposes (so there's no need to use GUI clients). I don't want to use JavaMail API since it requires me to write a lot of boilerplate code (e.g. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101254/e-mail-mime-message-parser).

It seems like Apache Commons Email and Simple Java Mail are no help.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the [SimpleJavaMail](http://www.simplejavamail.org) it is a good one.

Comment: A lot of boilerplate code?  The code in the question to which you’ve linked seems pretty concise to me.

Comment: @VGR, I mean If I were to write this code by myself then I guess I would be the one who should maintain that solution. That's why I don't want to just copy and paste the snippet from the question I've linked.

Comment: @nmorenor, could you please provide me with an example. Because I couldn't find such an example in the documentation. I'm sorry if this question is silly but I am just a  novice.

Comment: If you're looking for code that you can copy and paste without understanding it, you should probably give up now.  Without knowing more about your requirements, it's hard to direct you to the best solution.  Who's creating the emails that you want to read?  Are they all just plain text emails with simple content, or can they be arbitrarily complex?  What do you want to do with the content of the messages after you read it?